# HDFS-GPFS connector for using in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, biginsights

Is there a possibility to read data from IBM GPFS (Global Parallel Filesystem) in Apache Spark ?

My intention is to use something like this

```
sc.textFile("gfps://...")
```

instead of

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
```

The environment that is intended to be used is the Hortonworks Data Platform. I've read some [articles, deploying IBM Spectrum Scale File System](https://developer.ibm.com/storage/2017/06/27/deploying-ibm-spectrum-scale-file-system-using-apache-ambari-framework-hadoop-clusters/) that says you can configure on HDP, a connector to GPFS that will give you the ability to read/write to GPFS (maybe something the MAPR-FS has for it's file system). Have anyone done this ?

Thanks

Comment: you can use gpfs as local file `file:///"` or you can pass the mount point direct without `hdfs:// or `gpfs://` in our platform we use forexample `BINS/FILESOURCE` direct

Answer (score 0):

@dumitru You can use Sparkling.data library.

More details - http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/making-data-useful-with-the-sparkling-data-library-2/